# Laravel & Cashier : HasMany magic getter returns an empty string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-cashier

Using laravel/framework 8.0 and laravel/cashier 13.16

I use cashier to manage stripe subscriptions. As explained in the doc, because I don't use App\Models\User as the Billable Model, I declared my own Billable class in AppServiceProvider :

```php
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php


public function boot()
{
    Cashier::useCustomerModel(CustomClass::class);
    Cashier::useSubscriptionModel(Subscription::class);

    ...
}
```

In my CustomClass, I use the Billable Trait :

```php
class CustomClass extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, Billable;
}
```

This should give me access to an HasMany relation defined in the Billable trait :

```php
// ManagesSubscriptions.php (in the Billable Trait)

public function subscriptions(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cashier::$subscriptionModel, $this->getForeignKey())->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

My migrations are well played, in fact when I does

```php
dump($myClassInstance->subscriptions());
dump($myClassInstance->subscriptions()->count());
```

I get a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` object and `count` returns 1.

But the magic getter `$myClassInstance->subscriptions` returns an empty string. I'm new to laravel but it is supposed to return an object right ?

Moreover, this is used in Cashier webhook, `WebhookController` in the method `handleCustomerSubscriptionCreated` :

```php
if (! $user->subscriptions->contains('stripe_id', $data['id'])) {
```

But right here, I'm getting this error :

**Error: Call to a member function contains() on string**

Maybe I am missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, my Model was overriding the `getAttribute` method that is used by the magic method `__get` so some stuff happenned inside that prevented my relations to be returned.

So be careful when extending this method (I would even recommand not to do it ;))